# jQuery mouseover runs on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my jQuery

```
$('#samsungShine').mouseover(function () {
    $('#samsungShineImage').animate({
        "margin-left": "304px"
    }, 700);
}).mouseout(function () {
    $('#samsungShineImage').css("margin-left", "-304px");
});
```

When I mouseover, it works excellent, when I mouseout, it doesn't reset, it re-plays the mouseover... here is a fiddle of the problem so you can see what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/2tujd/

Comment: Try the `mouseenter` event

Comment: And try `mouseleave` event

Comment: you are having bubbling issues, since your mouseover handler introduces a new div that will then fire another mouseover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, using `stop` too:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2tujd/6/)

```
$('#samsungShine').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#samsungShineImage').animate({"margin-left":"304px"}, 700);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#samsungShineImage').stop().css("margin-left", "-304px");
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer, as it cancels the animation immediately onleave.

Comment: @iGanja It could be "better" with using `on`, but that's debatable if it helps. I just like being explicit. But you're right, the use of `stop` is pretty important.

Comment: Everyone likes to jump on the .on bandwagon (no pun intended,) but if we are binding to only one element, an explicit binding is just fine, and will run faster. I don't like to offer .on, unless we are addressing an obvious multiple binding situation.

Comment: @iGanja I don't understand what you mean. Explicit binding is the "long" way of binding event handlers. They're special cases that internally call `on`, so they're technically slower (although that "slower" is incredibly negligible...still, they're not "faster"). They do nothing different than `on`. Also, explicit binding requires chaining for multiple events (which this question/answer requires), while `on` can do it in a single call, probably more efficiently.

Comment: @iGanja Ian is correct, alias use on() internally, so on() is still faster

Comment: you and sweetamylase gave great answers, can I accept them both? lol

Comment: @roasted, you are correct, however my point was that we tend to offer .on in cases where we are binding directly to a single element, where as .on was originally designed to handle sets and take advantage of delegates. I've really not know an alias to be any slower or faster than using .on, but using .on with a delegate is slower than binding directly to the element, that's all I meant. Sorry for adding confusion to the topic. :)

Comment: @iGanja Well, I think using shortcut methods, like `.keyup()`, `.click()`, etc. is weird. There's only a handful of event types that are covered for this explicit way. Yet there are several more, and custom events, that can only be handled with `on`. So to me, it seems silly that they still have these shortcuts. At the same time, you're right that event delegation is slower (not by much, really), but that's not even comparable because you have to use a special overload for `on` and I never suggested that. And no problem for the confusion, I just wanted to make sure we all understood all this

Answer (score 9):

Try `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/2tujd/11/

```
$('#samsungShine').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#samsungShineImage').animate({
        "margin-left": "304px"
    }, 700);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('#samsungShineImage').stop().css("margin-left", "-304px");
});
```

On the [jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/), it says about using `mouseout` and simliarly for `mouseover`:

> This event type can cause many headaches due to event bubbling. For instance, when the mouse pointer moves out of the Inner element in this example, a mouseout event will be sent to that, then trickle up to Outer. This can trigger the bound mouseout handler at inopportune times.

**Edit:** Add `.stop()` inside `mouseleave` to make sure any current animation is stopped prior to setting the `margin-left`.

Comment: In your jsfiddle, if i enter/leave image repeatly and fast, animation no more works, that's why you should use stop too

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/2tujd/10/

I think its better to use just one handler. So you dont have any bubbling or problems with asynchronous methods.

```
$('#samsungShine').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#samsungShineImage').animate({
        "margin-left": "304px"
    }, 700, function() {
  $('#samsungShineImage').css("margin-left", "-304px")
  });
});
```

Comment: The OP wants the animate to reset ***ON MOUSEOUT/MOUSELEAVE***, not when the animation is complete.

Comment: That does not mean that it is the best way? why use 2 handlers when you can use one?

Comment: Plus you dont want to do a margin-left -304 when your animation is on +120 or something.

Comment: @S.Visser It's the "best" way because it's what the OP wants. The OP wants something to happen when the cursor enters the element (animate its `margin-left`), then do something different when the cursor leaves the element (reset its `margin-left`). You can't just assume it should be reset when the animation is done.